# gdebi doesn't work in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: gdebi, 21.04

I did a new install of Ubuntu 21.04 this weekend.
(I had problem with my 20.10 and needed a fresh start)
Earlier ha had used gdebi to install DEB-packages with graphical interface.
When I try to run gdebi now I get the error message:

gdebi-gtk
Download failed
Downloading the package failed: file " 'g-io-error-quark: Operation not supported (15)'

[image]

I tried to run gdebi on two different 21.04 computers with the same error.
I CAN run gdebi in the terminal, but that defies the purpose with gdebi)
Just to double check, I did a new install of 20.04 and there was no problem with gdebi.

Q: how do I get gdebi to work in a newly installed 21.04?

Comment: I noticed the same issue. If you create bug report against the gdebi-gtk package, please share the link and I will mark myself as impacted.

Comment: I used a temporary workaround for a similar issue and it seemed to work - but it does open a terminal window needlessly. Change `/usr/share/applications/gdebi.desktop` from Terminal=false to Terminal=true. The issues aren't identical, so I'm not completely confident that this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post this as a comment as it's only a workaround (not enough rep  points to comment, so this is "an answer" rather than "the answer"):

Modify the launcher to "run in terminal".
In XFCE, you can do that by right clicking on the launcher in the App menu and select "Edit Application". Then tick the checkbox: "Run in terminal".

I've not tested with other Desktops, but if the above is not available on your distro, KGill's workaround may work (see comments to original question).